# move my site profile information from one server to another

Tags: powershell, user-profile, my-site, user-profile-service, replication

I used central administration site collection backup to back up a My Site, and then used PowerShell restore-spsite to restore it on another server. All of the content moved, but the profile information ("ask me about," "past projects," the profile photo, etc.) did not move. How do I move the profile information?

Here is the script I used:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://sitename:81/my/username/ 
-Path c:\backup\mysite\username.bak -DatabaseServer servername 
-databasename WSS_Content -Force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving profile information to a new server can be accomplished by using the [User Profile Replication Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663011.aspx) to do a full replication from the old server to the new server. The UPRE is part of the [SharePoint 2010 Administration Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508849.aspx).